# spriteNodeWithTexture not loading in

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, textures

In my main menu I have a sound logo that I put at the bottom of the screen. I had it as spriteNoedeWithImageNamed but I need it so that when I tap on it it will change textures and I can't figure out how to do that without using textures. My problem is that I put it as textures and now it's not loading in at all. I know this is a simple problem but I've been going about this all day and I'm unable to think of a solution.

```
{
BOOL myBool;
//SKSpriteNode *soundLogo;
SKTexture *soundOn;
SKTexture *soundOff;
}

-(void) addSoundLogo:(CGSize)size {
SKSpriteNode *soundLogo = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:soundOn];
//resize sprite
soundLogo.size = CGSizeMake(soundLogo.size.width/2.25, soundLogo.size.height/2.25);
//position sprite
CGPoint myPoint = CGPointMake(65, 25);
soundLogo.position = myPoint;
//name sound logo
soundLogo.name = @"soundLogo";
//add action

[self addChild:soundLogo];


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to the scene. If it's a view controller substitute locationInNode: to locationInView:

If you need to add it to a different method instead of touchesBegan: you'll know how to do it now with textures. Make sure you put a cast on the return value before you init the pointer though to silence the warning.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //_bgLayer is the node that you put your SKSpriteNodes on.
    SKSpriteNode * node = (SKSpriteNode*)[_bgLayer nodeAtPoint:[[touches anyObject] locationInNode:_bgLayer]];
    //wallTile is the name of the texture you want it to be changed to.
    node.texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"wallTile"];
}
```

Hopefully this helps.